# Options to Import Data from MySql DB to MapR DB/HBase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, sqoop, mapr

I have a single table in MySql which contains around 24000000 records. I need a way to import this data into a table in MapR DB with multiple column families. I initially chose Sqoop as the tool to import the data but later found that I cannot use Sqoop to directly import the data as Sqoop does not support multiple column family import as yet.
I have populated the data in MapR FS using Sqoop from the MySql database.
What are my choices to import this data from MapR FS to MapR DB table with 3 column families?
It seems for bulk import, I have two choices:

- ImportTSV tool: this probably requires the source data to be in TSV format. But the data that I have imported in MapR FS from MySql using Sqoop seems to be in the CSV format. What is the standard solution for this approach?
- Write a custom Map Reduce program to translate the data in MapR FS to HFile and load it into MapR DB.

I just wanted to ensure that are these the only two choices available to load the data. This seems to be a bit restrictive given the fact that such a requirement is a very basic one in any system.
If custom Map Reduce is the way to go, an example or working sample would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you have some knowledge of Spark? Do you want to import directly or possibly using some temp hdfs storage? I'm working on a project of replicating data from Oracle to Hdfs and I have a working spark job which generates HFiles from initial snapshot(Avro files on hdfs dumped from Oracle using sqoop).

Comment: Your main problem is that you need to generate hfiles, I tried to find a working solution and I didn't find it so I write custom solution.

Comment: I am yet to work on Spark. So it might be not the best way for me as of now. But I will definitely keep this in mind. If I want to populate HBase/MapR DB from the mysql data, is a custom Map Reduce job the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

Create Hive table pointing to MapRDB using HBaseStorageHandler. You can use sqoop to import to hive table.

If you have already downloaded the data MapRFS. Use hive load command to load data to MapRDB.

Comment: I am not very sure I understand. Actually I am very new to the entire Hadoop/HBase eco-system. Can you explain a little bit more on the first option? For the second option, I can probably dump the MySql data using Sqoop to MapR FS. What you are suggesting is to load this MySql data dump from MapR FS to MapR DB using Hive load command. Not very sure about the role of Hive here. As per my knowledge Hive is more of a data warehouse equivalent in the Hadoop ecosystem. In any case, can you provide any links that might help me on how to import data from MapR FS/HDFS to MapRDb/HBase using Hive.

Comment: you can create Hive table pointing to MapRDB table, If you insert data to hive table, it populate MapRDB table. See here are the integration 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration